# Do NVDA addons have ability to execute on NVDA startup/shutdown?

Tags: nvda

I am trying to write an addon that does a thing when NVDA starts up.  I want it do something else when NVDA shuts down.  I have written a basic addon that uses input gestures to do my things... but are there event handlers or some other mechanism that I can use to tie into so I can do my things on NVDA startup/shutdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes.
https://github.com/nvdaaddons/DevGuide/wiki/NVDA-Add-on-Development-Guide#other-components

For GlobalPlugins, a constructor like so can be used for startup:

```
def __init__(self):
    super(GlobalPlugin, self).__init__()
    # DO STUFF
```

And a terminate() for shutdown:

```
def terminate(self):
    # DO STUFF
```